# How Do I make Multiple Entry Points in a .NET CORE app?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am new to .NET CORE but I have followed a few tutorials.  The tutorials I have followed are basically "Hello World" types of programs where I make a small functional .Net Core application and I publish it.  They are basically a DLL, I assume, and they run in some sort of system/container where they can run on any OS.

Even though the final product is a DLL, the code itself seems to be structured in a way where it is an actual executable application.

So how would I translate an actual C# DLL project into a .NET Core project?  How would a project that is already designed to produce a DLL work in a .Net Core project?

Comment: Executables only have one entrypoint: `static void Main`. .NET Libraries expose `public` methods which are all entrypoints in that sense I suppose. Remember an "entrypoint" in a program is where the operating system invokes an executable program file, the term does not apply to libraries. (and ASP.NET web-application files are really just libraries, the ASP.NET host just looks for certain exposed Page/Handler/Controller types).

Comment: that was fast.  Thanks Dai.  Your comment applies to ASP.NET  Does it also apply to .NET Core?  Also, when I ran my .NET Core applications, I did it from a special command line.  So how would that work if I translated a DLL C# program into a .NET Core program?

Comment: There is a good article which explains the process of hosting and running your assemblies under coreclr: 
[link](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/master/docs/core/tutorials/netcore-hosting.md)

Comment: Also Matt Warren has written the good article about running .Net executables: [link](http://mattwarren.org/2016/07/04/How-the-dotnet-CLI-tooling-runs-your-code/)